# Iterating a row of numbers, put a space behind all numbers under 10

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate a 10x10 board for Battleship, and I'd like to list the numbers from 1 to 10 before the rows so it'll be easier to oversee.
The problem is that 10 takes up more space than the other numbers and so indents the board by 1.

I tried a couple of things like making the for loop iterate a list, dedenting the numbers, tabbing the board with the help of the expandtabs method, and making an exception in the iteration by using enumerate, which I don't full understand. It seems so easy, but it's been frustrating me for a while.

This is what I originally have:

```
for rows in range(1, 11):
    print(rows, 10 * '* ' + "\n", end='')
```

And this is what I get:

```
1 * * * * * * * * * *
2 * * * * * * * * * *
3 * * * * * * * * * *
4 * * * * * * * * * *
5 * * * * * * * * * *
6 * * * * * * * * * *
7 * * * * * * * * * *
8 * * * * * * * * * *
9 * * * * * * * * * *
10 * * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format it properly:

```
for rows in range(1, 11):
    print('{:>2d}'.format(rows), 10 * '* ')
```

Yields:

```
 1 * * * * * * * * * * 
 2 * * * * * * * * * * 
 3 * * * * * * * * * * 
 4 * * * * * * * * * * 
 5 * * * * * * * * * * 
 6 * * * * * * * * * * 
 7 * * * * * * * * * * 
 8 * * * * * * * * * * 
 9 * * * * * * * * * * 
10 * * * * * * * * * *
```

For more on formatting, take a look at [this](https://pyformat.info/) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. The links to the documentation are very appreciated too.

Comment: Also doing `..+'\n', end='')` does not make sense. Simplify it as above.

Comment: Right, it makes it look much better as well. Not sure if I understand how the formatting works. Will do my best to get familiar with the document.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can enumerate the rows at the right side so the number 10 does not indent and you will receive something like

```
* * * * * * * * * * 1
* * * * * * * * * * 2
* * * * * * * * * * 3
* * * * * * * * * * 4
* * * * * * * * * * 5
* * * * * * * * * * 6
* * * * * * * * * * 7
* * * * * * * * * * 8
* * * * * * * * * * 9
* * * * * * * * * * 10
```

Or maybe you can start the numbers by cero

```
01 * * * * * * * * * *
02 * * * * * * * * * *
03 * * * * * * * * * *
04 * * * * * * * * * *
05 * * * * * * * * * *
06 * * * * * * * * * *
07 * * * * * * * * * *
08 * * * * * * * * * *
09 * * * * * * * * * *
10 * * * * * * * * * *
```

Or even use a condition to add an extra space if the number is not 10, something like:

```
if(number < 10) 
    print(rows, ' ' + 10 * '* ' + "\n", end='')
else
    print(rows, 10 * '* ' + "\n", end='')
```

So you should get something like this:

```
1  * * * * * * * * * *
2  * * * * * * * * * *
3  * * * * * * * * * *
4  * * * * * * * * * *
5  * * * * * * * * * *
6  * * * * * * * * * *
7  * * * * * * * * * *
8  * * * * * * * * * *
9  * * * * * * * * * *
10 * * * * * * * * * *
```

And the easiest solution would be start counting the rows by 0, so you don't have to use the number 10:

```
0  * * * * * * * * * *
1  * * * * * * * * * *
2  * * * * * * * * * *
3  * * * * * * * * * *
4  * * * * * * * * * *
5  * * * * * * * * * *
6  * * * * * * * * * *
7  * * * * * * * * * *
8  * * * * * * * * * *
9  * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for any number of rows:

```
def PrintTable(numOfRows):
    row = numOfRows * ' *'
    formatString = '{}{}{}'.format('{:', len(str(numOfRows)), 'd}{}')
    print('\n'.join([formatString.format(i, row) for i in range(1, numOfRows + 1)]))
```

Comment: Seems very complicated for what I'm trying to achieve. But dunno, I'm still a beginner. Thank you very much though!

Comment: @mwaning: `print(formatString)` might help you to understand.